# GCP Compute Engine using Terraform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, devops, google-compute-engine

How to provision multiple instances in GCP Compute Engine using Terraform. I've tried using 'count' parameter in the resource block. But terraform is not provisioning more than one instance because the VM with a particular name is created once when first count is executed.

```
provider "google" {
version = "3.5.0"
credentials = file("battleground01-5c86f5873d44.json")
project = "battleground01"
region  = "us-east1"
zone    = "us-east1-b"
}

variable "node_count" {
default = "3"
}


resource "google_compute_instance" "appserver" {
count = "${var.node_count}"
name = "battleground"
machine_type = "f1-micro"


boot_disk {
initialize_params {
image = "debian-cloud/debian-9"
}
}

network_interface {
network = "default"
}

}
```

Comment: Please add some terraform code to the question or your question will probably be closed.

Comment: You aren't using your count variable in the machine name, please reread the terraform documentation on https://www.terraform.io/language/meta-arguments/count#basic-syntax the aws example is extremely similar to what you are doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for this to work, you would have to make a slight change in the way you are naming your compute instances:

```
provider "google" {
  version     = "3.5.0"
  credentials = file("battleground01-5c86f5873d44.json")
  project     = "battleground01"
  region      = "us-east1"
  zone        = "us-east1-b"
}

variable "node_count" {
  type    = number
  default = 3
}


resource "google_compute_instance" "appserver" {
  count        = var.node_count
  name         = "battleground-${count.index}"
  machine_type = "f1-micro"


  boot_disk {
    initialize_params {
      image = "debian-cloud/debian-9"
    }
  }

  network_interface {
    network = "default"
  }

}
```

As you are using the `count` meta-argument, the way to access the array index is by using the `count.index` attribute [1]. You have also set the `node_count` variable default value to be a string and even though it would probably get converted to a number by Terraform, make sure to use the right variable types.

---

[1] https://www.terraform.io/language/meta-arguments/count#the-count-object